# Can I make a call to the main ViewController so I can create more objects for my game?

Tags: swift

I need to call my `viewDidLoadBy()` again to create a new shape in my game. But I cant seam to grasp how to do this. Do I need to delete the current instance before continuing? This is whats in my main TetrisViewController
which has TetrisModel and TetrisView files as its disposal. I created a instance but now I like to create another, any suggestions or clarifications would be great.

Here is what I doing in my TetrisViewControler.swift that creates a shape in my game.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //let centerX = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) / blockSize * blockSize / 2
        let randoNumber = randomShapeGenerator()
            if randoNumber == 0{
                let grid = QTetrisGrid()
                block = TetrisBlockView(color: UIColor.orange, grid: grid, blockSize: blockSize,
                                        startY: 120.0, boardCenterX: CGFloat(135.0))
            }
            if randoNumber == 1{
                let grid = ZTetrisGrid()
                block = TetrisBlockView(color: UIColor.orange, grid: grid, blockSize: blockSize,
                                        startY: 120.0, boardCenterX: CGFloat(135.0))
            }
            if randoNumber == 3{
                let grid = JTetrisGrid()
                block = TetrisBlockView(color: UIColor.orange, grid: grid, blockSize: blockSize,
                                        startY: 120.0, boardCenterX: CGFloat(135.0))
            }
            if randoNumber == 4{
                let grid = ITetrisGrid()
                block = TetrisBlockView(color: UIColor.orange, grid: grid, blockSize: blockSize,
                                        startY: 120.0, boardCenterX: CGFloat(135.0))
            }
            if randoNumber == 5{
                let grid = STetrisGrid()
                block = TetrisBlockView(color: UIColor.orange, grid: grid, blockSize: blockSize,
                                        startY: 120.0, boardCenterX: CGFloat(135.0))
            }

        tetrisBoard = TetrisBoardView(withFrame: UIScreen.main.bounds, blockSize: blockSize, circleRadius: 1 )
        view.addSubview(tetrisBoard)
        print("Center of block before animation: \(block.center)")

        print("Bounds of main screen is \(UIScreen.main.bounds)")
        view.addSubview(block)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only code that is appropriate for viewDidLoad is for setting up the initial state of the view, in this case the game board itself. Drawing shapes should come in a main run loop, which is common in game programming.

However, to answer your specific question, you need to decompose your code into a separate function. pseudo code...

```
func addRandomShapeToBoard() {
  // insert the code you have above
}
```

Then you can call it from other functions, instead of just inside viewDidLoad